# write a program to print the array elements in zigzagarray

Tags: c, arrays

Suppose we have array provided with few elements:

```
arr[]={5,8,7,25,-2,2,25}
```

We want it to be printed like max, min alternately:

```
arr[]={25,-2,25,2,8,5,7} //output
```

Main function would look like this:

```
int main()
{
   int arr[]={5,8,7,25,-2,2,25} ;
   int res_size  ;
   int *res;
   int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

   res=rearrange(arr, n, &res_size);

   for(int i=0;i<res_size;i++)
      printf("%d\t",res[i]);
   return 0;
}

// complete the function..
int *rearrange(int*arr, int size, int *res_size)
{
//complete the body with proper return type...

}
```

I was able to write the program for it, but wasn't able to find what will be the return type. So my output wasn't matching to any test cases.

Please someone complete the rearrange function with specific return type. What is `res_size` meant for?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the res_size argument inside your rearrange function. And the return type for rearrange should be void if you just want to modify your array in itself. If you want to create a copy of your array and modify that, you can explicitly do that and call rearrange on the copied array, or you can have the return type for rearrange be an array full of integers.

As for the algorithm to get the array as you want, here is the pseudocode:

1. First order numbers in increasing order. Can use an algorithm like quicksort: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort or any other sorting algorithm.
2. Then have a while loop that has a counter start from 0 and go until the length of your array. You also have two pointers pointing to each end of the sorted array. You increment the counter after you return a number (or add it to the rearranged array).
3. Then, when counter is 0 or even, you return the value pointed by the pointer on the greater number end. When counter is odd, you return the value pointed by the pointer on the lower number end. Each time after a pointer returns the number it points you, you push it down the list.
4. You don't have to worry about wondering when to stop regarding the pointers because your while loop is set for the length of the array.

Comment: i agree that we can do without  res_size  argument inside rearrange function.  i got this question on hackerrank, so  the function rearrange is correct and all argument are valid, i want the function body to be completed without any modifiction  with exact  return type that it should must be printing in zigzagarray.